# Ajuda em exercício de alocação dinâmica em C

Tags: c

O exercício é o seguinte:

O Brasil acabou de comprar um novo território onde será construído o mais novo estado brasileiro. Ao contrário dos outros estados, este terá toda a sua infraestrutura planejada e, para isso, pediram a sua ajuda.

O novo estado é dividido em N cidades e, a princípio, não existe nenhuma estrada ligando qualquer uma delas. Seu trabalho será cadastrar novas estradas construídas ou informar se existe uma estrada ligando duas cidades específicas.

Para isso você receberá dois valores inteiros: N(N <= 1000, representando o número de cidades) e Q(número de operações que você deverá realizar). Seguem Q linhas onde cada uma delas irá conter um char C e dois inteiros X e Y. O char pode ser 'c' ou 'v' que indicam operações de cadastro ou verificação, respectivamente. (cuidado com a leitura do char para não ler o \n por engano). Os inteiros X e Y correspondem às cidades em questão (as cidades são numeradas de 0 a N-1).

ATENÇÃO: é obrigatório o uso de alocação dinâmica para resolver este exercício. Não se esqueça de liberar corretamente toda a memória alocada.

Note que todas as estradas construídas serão de mão dupla, então adicionar uma estrada entre X e Y implica em adicionar entre Y e X.

No caso de uma verificação, você deverá escrever uma linha "Existe uma estrada entre [X] e [Y]." caso ela exista ou "Nao existe uma estrada entre [X] e [Y]." caso contrário. Há ainda a chance das cidades informadas não existirem. Nesses casos, imprima uma linha “Nao existem as cidades [X] e [Y].” caso as duas cidades não existam ou “Nao existe a cidade [X/Y].” caso uma das duas cidades não exista;

(As variáveis entre [] devem ser substituídas por seus respectivos valores, cheque o exemplo de saída para melhor compreensão)

Exemplos de entrada e saída:

Entrada:

```
2 3
c 2 3
c 4 3
c 5 3
```

Saída:

```
Nao existem as cidades 2 e 3.
Nao existem as cidades 4 e 3.
Nao existem as cidades 5 e 3.
```

Meu código ficou assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *alocar_vetor_char (int q) {
    char* ptrc;
    ptrc = malloc (q * sizeof(char));
    return ptrc; 
}

int **alocar_matriz_int (int q) {
    int** ptri;
    ptri = malloc (q * sizeof(int*));
    for (int i = 0; i < q; i++) {
        ptri[i] = malloc (2 * sizeof(int));
    }
    return ptri;
}

void liberar_memoria (char *vet, int **mat, int q) {
    free(vet);
    for (int i = 0; i < q; i++) {
        free(mat[i]);
    }
    free(mat);
}

int main (void) {

    int n, q;
    char* ptrc; // ponteiro para o vetor de char
    int** ptri; // ponteiro para a matriz de int

    scanf("%d %d", &n, &q);

    ptrc = alocar_vetor_char(q);
    ptri = alocar_matriz_int(q);

    for (int i = 0; i < q; i++) {
        scanf("%c ", &ptrc[i]);
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            scanf("%d ", &ptri[i][j]);
        }
    }

    char cadastro[n][n] // matriz que verifica se as cidades i e j possuem estrada entre si, no qual 1 é sim e 0 é não

    for (int k = 0; k < q; k++) {
        switch (ptrc[k]) {
            case 'c':
                if (ptri[k][0] < n && ptri[k][0] >= 0) { // verificacao se o primeiro valor de entrada e valido
                    if (ptri[k][1] < n && ptri[k][1] >= 0) {
                        cadastro[ptri[k][0]][ptri[k][1]] = 1; // adiciona 1 a cadastro[i][j]
                        cadastro[ptri[k][1]][ptri[k][0]] = 1; // adiciona 1 a cadastro[j][i]
                    } else {
                        printf("Nao existe a cidade %d.\n", ptri[k][1]);
                    }
                } else {
                    if (ptri[k][1] >= n || ptri[k][1] < 0) { // verificacao se o segundo valor de entrada e valido
                        printf("Nao existem as cidades %d e %d.\n", ptri[k][0], ptri[k][1]);
                    } else {
                        printf("Nao existe a cidade %d.\n", ptri[k][0]);
                    }                    
                }
            break;
            case 'v':
                if (ptri[k][0] < n && ptri[k][0] >= 0) { // verificacao se o primeiro valor de entrada e valido
                    if (ptri[k][1] < n && ptri[k][1] >= 0) { // verificacao se o segundo valor de entrada e valido
                        if (cadastro[ptri[k][0]][ptri[k][1]] == 1 && cadastro[ptri[k][1]][ptri[k][0]] == 1) { // condicao que verifica se cadastro[i][j] e cadastro [j][i] possui valor 1
                            printf("Existe uma estrada entre %d e %d.\n", ptri[k][0], ptri[k][1]);
                        } else {
                            printf("Nao existe uma estrada entre %d e %d.\n", ptri[k][0], ptri[k][1]);
                        }                         
                    } else {
                        printf("Nao existe a cidade %d.\n", ptri[k][1]);
                    }
                } else {
                    if (ptri[k][1] >= n || ptri[k][1] < 0) { // verificacao se o segundo valor de entrada e valido
                        printf("Nao existem as cidades %d e %d.\n", ptri[k][0], ptri[k][1]);
                    } else {
                        printf("Nao existe a cidade %d.\n", ptri[k][0]);
                    }                    
                }
            break;
            default:
            break;
        }
    }    

    liberar_memoria(ptrc, ptri, q);

    return 0;
}
```

O meu problema é que a última linha da saída nunca é printada na tela, ficando algo como:

```
2 3
c 2 3
c 4 3
c 5 3
Nao existem as cidades 2 e 3.
Nao existem as cidades 4 e 3.
```

Ao invés de:

```
2 3
c 2 3
c 4 3
c 5 3
Nao existem as cidades 2 e 3.
Nao existem as cidades 4 e 3.
Nao existem as cidades 5 e 3.
```

E eu não sei qual é o problema.

Comment: Você não deveria fazer a alocação dinâmica de cadastro[n][n]? Em tempo de compilação o valor da variável n não é conhecido.

Comment: "última linha da saída nunca é printada na tela": e como deveria ser a última linha ?

Comment: @anonimo Na verdade, tanto faz. Eu não fiz alocação dinâmica pra usar menos memória e menos linhas de código, uma vez que cadastro vai ser sempre uma matriz quadrada de ordem n (n é o número de cidades, cujo valor é dado pelo usuário). Então não faz diferença se eu alocar dinamicamente ou não a matriz.

Comment: @zentrunix Editei a pergunta pra mostrar como deveroa ser a última linha.

Comment: E porque você acha que o compilador irá alocar o espaço de memória correto se apenas durante a execução você lerá o valor da variável n?

Comment: @anonimo: C99 permite arrays dinâmicos...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você teve problemas com scanf. Abaixo vai o fonte corrigido. Coloquei também alguns printf para debug (estranhamente parece que os professores não ensinam isso).

PS. Sempre que se usa a função scanf é aconselhável testar o retorno.
Assim:

```
n = scanf("%d%d", &i, &j);
if (n != 2)
{
  // ocorreu algum erro na digitacao
  // ....
}
```

Não quis alterar seu código para colocar essa consistência, mas é fatal, quem faz não esses testes apanha com scanf.

Agora seu programa corrigido.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *alocar_vetor_char (int q)
{
  char* ptrc;
  ptrc = malloc (q * sizeof(char));
  return ptrc; 
}

int **alocar_matriz_int (int q)
{
  int** ptri;
  ptri = malloc (q * sizeof(int*));
  for (int i = 0; i < q; i++)
  {
    ptri[i] = malloc (2 * sizeof(int));
  }
  return ptri;
}

void liberar_memoria (char *vet, int **mat, int q)
{
  free(vet);
  for (int i = 0; i < q; i++) {
    free(mat[i]);
  }
  free(mat);
}

int main (void)
{

  int n, q;
  char* ptrc; // ponteiro para o vetor de char
  int** ptri; // ponteiro para a matriz de int

  printf("* digite 'n' e 'q': ");
  scanf("%d %d", &n, &q);

  ptrc = alocar_vetor_char(q);
  ptri = alocar_matriz_int(q);

  for (int i = 0; i < q; i++) {
    printf("* digite linha %d: ", i);
    scanf(" %c", &ptrc[i]);              // <---------------------------
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
      scanf("%d", &ptri[i][j]);          // <---------------------------
    }
    printf("* linha %d: c=%c\n", i, ptrc[i]);
  }

  char cadastro[n][n]; // matriz que verifica se as cidades i e j possuem estrada entre si, no qual 1 é sim e 0 é não

  for (int k = 0; k < q; k++)
  {
    switch (ptrc[k])
    {
      case 'c':
        printf("* case c: k=%d\n", k); /// <------------- para debug
        if (ptri[k][0] < n && ptri[k][0] >= 0) { // verificacao se o primeiro valor de entrada e valido
          if (ptri[k][1] < n && ptri[k][1] >= 0) {
            cadastro[ptri[k][0]][ptri[k][1]] = 1; // adiciona 1 a cadastro[i][j]
            cadastro[ptri[k][1]][ptri[k][0]] = 1; // adiciona 1 a cadastro[j][i]
          } else {
            printf("Nao existe a cidade %d.\n", ptri[k][1]);
          }
        } else {
          if (ptri[k][1] >= n || ptri[k][1] < 0) { // verificacao se o segundo valor de entrada e valido
            printf("Nao existem as cidades %d e %d.\n", ptri[k][0], ptri[k][1]);
          } else {
            printf("Nao existe a cidade %d.\n", ptri[k][0]);
          }
        }
        break;

      case 'v':
        printf("* case v: k=%d\n", k); // <------------------------ para debug
        if (ptri[k][0] < n && ptri[k][0] >= 0) { // verificacao se o primeiro valor de entrada e valido
          if (ptri[k][1] < n && ptri[k][1] >= 0) { // verificacao se o segundo valor de entrada e valido
            if (cadastro[ptri[k][0]][ptri[k][1]] == 1 && cadastro[ptri[k][1]][ptri[k][0]] == 1) { // condicao que verifica se cadastro[i][j] e cadastro [j][i] possui valor 1
              printf("Existe uma estrada entre %d e %d.\n", ptri[k][0], ptri[k][1]);
            } else {
              printf("Nao existe uma estrada entre %d e %d.\n", ptri[k][0], ptri[k][1]);
            }
          } else {
            printf("Nao existe a cidade %d.\n", ptri[k][1]);
          }
        } else {
          if (ptri[k][1] >= n || ptri[k][1] < 0) { // verificacao se o segundo valor de entrada e valido
            printf("Nao existem as cidades %d e %d.\n", ptri[k][0], ptri[k][1]);
          } else {
            printf("Nao existe a cidade %d.\n", ptri[k][0]);
          }
        }
        break;

      default:
        printf("* case default: k=%d (ptrc[%d]=%c)\n", k, k, ptrc[k]); // para debug
        break;
    }
  }

  liberar_memoria(ptrc, ptri, q);

  return 0;
}
```

Explicação: sempre que se usa o formato "%c" deve-se colocar um espaço antes, assim: " %c" para consumir espaços e fim de linha antes da leitura do próximo caracter.

O outro problema de formato era "%d " (com espaço após o %d)...aparentemente este espaço adicional não casava com o fim de linha após a digitação do segundo número (por exemplo: c 2 4ENTER).